# Magento how to retain guest billing address details when navigating away from one-page checkout

Tags: javascript, php, magento, cookies, checkout

I have researched this for days, but cannot find a solution. The Magento version is 1.9.2.4.

The scenario is that the customer is a Guest. They select their products and then proceed to the one-page checkout and fill out their name and address details. They then wish to modify their cart and navigate back to the shop to add more products. When they return to the checkout page their name and address details have disappeared, and they have to re-enter them.

I am able to create cookies to store first-name, surname etc. when they continue to the Delivery Information section by modifying the continue button in persistent\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml as below:

```
`<button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Continue')) ?>" class="button" onclick="set_billing_cookies()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
```

and adding JavaScript as follows:

```
function set_billing_cookies(){    
firstname = document.getElementById('billing:firstname').value;
createCookie('guestfirstname',firstname,7);
billing.save();  
   }
```

This works and I can see the cookies being generated before moving to billing.save();

The problem is how to read the cookies back in when the customer returns to the site. I have tried using window.onload = function ... to try to use javascript to read the cookies and populate the billing address fields in two places

1. persistent\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml
2. checkout\onepage.phtml

Neither work. I realise that the page is only actually loaded once, and is managed via AJAX.

Where should I add my JavaScript to read the cookies and how can I populate the fields?

Or should I be trying something using sessions?

This must be an issue for many Magento sites. Am I missing a really simple solution here. Or do I have to buy a commercial checkout extension to get this functionality?

Help please!!

Answer (score 0):

Update. I was making a syntax error in the Javascript for reading the cookies. The solution above works. Save /generate all your cookies on ....billing.phtml and read them on .....onepage.phtml once it has loaded.

Comment: FWIW I'd store that data in LocalStorage - saves passing it across to the server in a cookie header every page request.